# Create columns in a pandas data frame with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of variable names, `var_list`, and I want to make sure they exist in a pandas data frame. I achieved so with:

```
for cname in var_list:
    if cname not in df.columns:
        df[i]=0
```

Is it possible to do the same with a list comprehension, like:

```
[df[i]=0 for i in var_list not if df.columns]
```

or any other "more compact" way?

Comment: a bit unclear. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Making a list just to throw away later is not an ideal practice. Instead, how about using `pd.DataFrame.get`: `for cname in var_list: df[cname] = df.get(cname, 0)`?